# Como poner un valor predeterminado en un select en Angular

Tags: angular, formularios, select

mi situación es que estoy desarrollando un formulario en Angular para poder editar o cambiar un dato el cual ha sido ingresado a través de un SELECT, mi inquietud es como podría poner como dato predeterminado del SELECT el dato que se va a editar? muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
  <div class="form-group col-4">
    <label for="inputEmail4">Ciudad de origen</label>
    <select formControlName="ciudadOrigen" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="" id="">
      <option *ngFor="let ciudades of ciudades" [value]="ciudades.valor" selected="">{{ciudades.valor}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola!. 
Podrias facilitar el .Ts de tu componente asi te ayudaria dentro del propio contexto.

Answer (score 0):

En el select utilizas value="XX"

```
  <div class="form-group col-4">
    <label for="inputEmail4">Ciudad de origen</label>
    <select formControlName="ciudadOrigen" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="" id="" value="10">
      <option *ngFor="let ciudades of ciudades" [value]="ciudades.valor" selected="">{{ciudades.valor}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```